# python lxml xpath: how to get this predicate working

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, predicate

Good Morning,

Recently I picked up python and web scraping as a hobby ...

I'm trying to get my head around an issue with python lxml and xpath predicates but alas - apparently there's nothing similar on stackoverflow. So I managed to reproduce in below code, hoping someone sees what I don't ...

Is there somebody who can explain why the Result3 is an empty list?
I was expecting Result3 to be the same as Result1.

How can I achieve that Result3 = Result1 ?

Versions: Python 3.7.3, lxml 4.4.0 (installed using pip, not Christoph Gohlke's binary) on an AMD windows machine.

Thanks in advance!

Stef

```
import lxml.html

simple_record  = """<a href="some_map/some_file.png">dododo</a>"""
tree           = lxml.html.fromstring(simple_record)

simple_xpath   = "@href"
found_field    = tree.xpath(simple_xpath)
print("Result1 = {}".format(found_field))

simple_xpath   = """contains(@href,"some_file")"""
found_field    = tree.xpath(simple_xpath)
print("Result2 = {}".format(found_field))

simple_xpath   = """@href[contains(@href,"some_file")]"""
found_field    = tree.xpath(simple_xpath)
print("Result3 = {}".format(found_field))
```

**Actual output:**

```
Result1 = ['some_map/some_file.png']
Result2 = True
Result3 = []
```

**Expected output:**

```
Result1 = ['some_map/some_file.png']
Result2 = True
Result3 = ['some_map/some_file.png']
```

Comment: Your third XPath should be """@href[contains(.,"some_file")]""" as your first reference to @href makes it the context. Untested as I don't have lxml available.

Comment: The `contains()` function has not the same semantic as `starts-with()` function. Without input sample, everything else in the question is meaningless.

Comment: @Alejandro thanks for pointing that out, the use of `starts-with()` was a leftover, I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate in the third example (`@href[contains(@href,"some_file")]`), translated into English means "find a node in `simple_record` which has an attribute `href` which itself has an attribute `href` which has an attribute value containing the string `some_file`". Such node doesn't exist, so an empty result list is returned.

What you intended to ask, in English, is "find a node in `simple_record` which has an attribute `href` which has a value containing the string `some_file`" (Thanks @DanielHaley!) . Translated into xpath, you would write it as

```
simple_xpath   = '@href[contains(.,"some_file")]'
```

The `.` now refers back to the context node that is being filtered by the predicate (i.e. the `@href` attribute itself). That expression would cause Result 3 to be the same as Result 1.

Comment: I think your English translations are a little off. I think the first one is more like "find an `href` attribute which itself has an attribute `href` which has a value containing the string `some_file`". The second would be more like "find an `href` attribute which has a value containing the string `some_file`".

Comment: @DanielHaley - You're right! That's what happens when you do translation without enough coffee! Will edit.